# modeling node.js with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm pretty new to Node.js and I'm starting a new web app just to study.
So, I'm using Mongoose.js and this is my model:

The party schema:

```
var PartySchema = new Schema({
  created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  title: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
    trim: true
  },
  createdBy: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  },
  invitations: [{
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Invitation'
  }]
});
```

The Invitation schema:

```
var InvitationSchema = new Schema({
  party: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Party'
  }
});
```

Ok,
So I wrote a test case like this, assume the other variable (party) is correctly initialized:

```
invitation = new Invitation({
  party: party,
  content: 'come to this awesome party'
});
```

When I pass this variable invitation to a method like this:

```
return Party.sendInvitation(invitation, function(err, invitation) {
  should.exist(invitation);
  should.not.exist(err);
  done();
});
```

Accessing invitation.party inside the sendInvitation method is like this:

```
invitation.party[525439f929cf32be02000003]
```

As seem, I can't navigate through `invitation.party`.
How can I achieve this `invitation.party.title`?

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

For test case, I think you can use data from query invitation with populate data from party.

```
Invitation
.findById(id)
.populate('title')
.exec(function (err, invitation) {
  if (!err) 
     return invitation; //this invitation data must be contained party with title. invitation.party.title
})
```